# Angular 6: ViewContainerRef.createComponent with custom provider

Tags: angular

My Angular 6 service creates a component dynamically:

```
buildComponent(viewContainerRef) {
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  ...
}
```

The component I'm creating needs a handle to `viewContainerRef` in its constructor.  How can I pass it from the service while I create the component?  Is there a way to perhaps customize the injector that is used when `createComponent` executes? (hint: I notice that `injector` is one of the params to `createComponent`)

I have tried to pass the container to the component on the next line, with something like:

```
componentRef.instance.viewContainer = viewContainerRef;
```

This doesn't work for me though because I need the container reference to be available immediately upon construction if possible.

Comment: use ng-container to create customcomponent

Comment: @Chellappan Please elaborate

Comment: use ng-container to get access viewcontainer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I succeeded by creating a custom injector and providing it as the 3rd param to `viewContainerRef.createComponent`.  Here is my service code:

```
constructor(
  private injector: Injector, 
  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

buildComponent(viewContainerRef) {
  const inj: Injector = this.makeCustomInjector(viewContainerRef);
  const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
  const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory, undefined, inj);
}

makeCustomInjector(viewContainerRef) {
  return Injector.create({
    providers: [{provide: ViewContainerRef, useValue: viewContainer}],
    parent: this.injector
  });
}
```

Now the `MyComponent` parent Injector has the viewContainerRef I want. The final step, to be able to inject that view container into the component, is to tell the component to ignore its own injector and take from its parent.  This is the `MyComponent` constructor:

```
constructor(@SkipSelf() viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef){}
```

SkipSelf comes from `@angular/core`